# Creating a simple PPTP/L2TP VPN with Ethernet bridging

Tags: linux, vpn, home-networking, raspberry-pi

I'm looking into creating a very simple VPN on my home network using a Raspberry Pi.

Such VPN is designed to allow me to send WOL (`Wake on LAN`) packets from a remote device and accessing Samba shares.

Though the first can be achieved slightly differently, this could be a valid excercise to me (only reason why I'm not posting in serverfault).

I mentioned PPTP/L2TP **only** because they are both supported by Windows and Android without additional software. Though OpenVPN uses industry standards, I think I can't use it to configure Windows and Android **native** VPN support.

I have read (in OpenVPN documentation) about IP-bridged VPNs and Ethernet-bridged VPNs, opting for the second.

#### Question(s)

- What Linux server software is to be used to create such networks?
- Can you link some tutorials just in case? (I can search for them once I know what software to use)
- Can I use my home DHCP for assigning IP addresses?

Comment: This question must go to the desired stackexchange page, http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . By the way, I use openvpn on raspberry pi like server and android, windows, linux like clients and works really nice. http://raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/1-openvpn-server-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

> **Question(s)**
>
> What Linux server software is to be used to create such networks?

The *openvpn* and *bridge-utils* packages, installable through your regular package manager. It will bring along a host of other packages, including *openssl* and the like. If you are not on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, *bridge-utils* may have a different name.

> Can you link some tutorials just in case? (I can search for them once I know what software to use)

[This is a good tutorial](http://www.linuxsysadmintutorials.com/setup-openvpn-with-bridging-support-on-ubuntu/).

> Can I use my home DHCP for assigning IP addresses?

No need to. If you are using OpenVPN, it will do this automagically.